# How Can I get both Incoming and Outgoing transactions from "getAssetTransfers" inside one request?

Tags: transactions, alchemy, alchemy-sdk

I'm working with [alchemy's SDK](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-get-transaction-history-for-an-address-on-ethereum).

And as per the Alchemy SDK documentation, it says we can get all the transactions

like this:

```
const config = {
  apiKey: "<-- ALCHEMY APP API KEY -->",
  network: Network.ETH_MAINNET,
};
const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);

const data = await alchemy.core.getAssetTransfers({
  fromBlock: "0x0",
  toAddress: "0x5c43B1eD97e52d009611D89b74fA829FE4ac56b1",
  category: ["external", "internal", "erc20", "erc721", "erc1155"],
});
```

If I need Outgoing transactions, I will send `fromAddress` instead.

**Q) Can we get both inside one API request?**
Like this:

```
 const data = await alchemy.core.getAssetTransfers({
    fromBlock: "0x0",
    toAddress: address,
    fromAddress: address,
    category: ["external", "internal", "erc20", "erc721"],
  });
```

I tried adding both `fromAddress` and `toAddress` but it didn't work.